# Can i use a ternary operator instead of while loop

Tags: ruby, while-loop, ternary-operator

I'm trying to reduce the while loop below to a single line

```
def this_method(week)
  i = 0
  while i < array.length
    yield(week[i])
    i += 1
  end
end

week.each do |week|
  puts week
end
```

Comment: Answer is no. You can't use ternary operator to replace while loop. Each have different use case.

Comment: The only thing i can think of to do is to convert the while loop to a function so i can call the loop - would that be the best way?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The ternary operator might simplify some operations but often, it can leave your code difficult to maintain / understand when you revisit.

Comment: I want to make the code shorter and readable to also to clearly understand the use of various operators i.e what they can and can't do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like others, I'm confused about the example (`array` is not defined, and `this_method` is never called). But you certainly don't need the while loop. I'd just use the `Integer#times` method, since you're making no use of the array values:

```
array.length.times {|i| yield week[i]}
```

`#each_index` (which ram suggested) works just as well.

But if `array` is actually meant to be `week`, then it gets even simpler:

```
week.each {|x| yield x}
```

I'm not sure why you'd want to create a method that just recycles `#each` though.

Comment: Well, I'm confused as well but I think `array` can be method that returns, in this case, an array.

Comment: Sorry, array should be 'week'. I've been playing around with it, assigning the array different arrays. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

For since line you can use [`Array#each_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index):

```
array.each_index {|i| yield week[i] }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. The ternary operator is a conditional expression, the while is a loop expression.

However, in Ruby you normally use enumerators, not while. Your code can be rewritten as

```
def this_method(week)
  array.each_with_index { |item, i| yield(week[i]) }
end
```

What is not clear to me, is there the `array` variable comes from. Even in your example, there is no definition of such variable.

Comment: Sorry, array should be 'week'. I've been playing around with it, assigning the array different arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`if` in any form check conditions **only** once.
`while` on other hand, can check conditions many times.

Well, if you don't like other answers with enumerators you  can use while in a different form:

```
def this_method(week)
  i = -1
  yield(week[i]) while (i+=1) < array.length
end
```